# Add new fields on the wp_users table

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

This is kind of a noob question.

I just want to know if it's okay to add new fields for the wp_users table?

Or should I create a new table? example wp_users_information

The reason that I asked the question is that maybe some future updates of wordpress might reset the wp_users fields to default.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use user_meta.

You can refer to this codex.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

No, I would suggest to use usermeta table or a new custom table instead of adding column to wp_users table.